# Convert Text Field in Database to Match Rule

Tags: php, mysql

i've run into the following problem:

a customer has provided us with a large database of holiday offers. The offers are also priced. The following structure is given

Table

```
offers
```

Field

```
roomprice1
```

Unfortunately, the roomprice1 field is declared as "VARCHAR" and therefore not suitable for comparing/sorting for example with "ORDER BY roomprice1 ASC/DESC.

Is there a way (PHP/SQL) to convert the field so that ordering in the right manner would be possible?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: it doesn't matter if it's a `varchar` or `Int` you will be allowed to `order by`... show us your query.

Comment: assuming the prices aren't in stupid textual formats, e.g. `$10 dollars`, you can just `alter table` and convert roomprice1 to a decimal field, then do straight numeric sorting. @jcho360. yes, it does matter. `100.00` would sort as smaller than `99.99`, because 1 < 9

Comment: no he can't - order by will not order correctly if he use varchar

Answer (score 0):

If you can query and edit the db by yourself, then do this:

```
ALTER TABLE  `offers` CHANGE  `offers`  `roomprice1` INT( 255 )
```

---

Otherwise, if you want to use PHP, prepare a query like this with PDO or mysqli:

```
SELECT `roomprice1` FROM `offers`
```

and iterate through the results with php, using [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to convert from string to integer. For each iteration, put the new value in another table with `INSERT` or save it in a PHP array which you can then [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cast function to reorder it if you don't want to alter the table.

```
 ...ORDER BY CAST('roomprice1' AS DECIMAL(10,2));
```

Rather than just the normal 'ORDER BY'

Here is an additional link if you want to more about casting:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast